# Why do Mysql return error code 1241 on Update query?

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql Workbench 8.0.12, I have a table (`tblproduction`) with three columns:

```
idProduction INT PK AI
dateProduction DATETIME
statusProduction VARCHAR(15)
```

When I try to change the value of the column `statusProduction` for example, from 'queue' to 'done' as the query below (SELECT, INSERT AND DELETE querys are OK):

```
UPDATE tblproduction 
SET statusProduction = 'done'
WHERE idProduction=1;
```

The system returns `"Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)."`
I've done some research and found out that this error code is related to syntax errors, but I didn't find any problem on my query.

If I try to do something like this:

```
UPDATE tblproduction 
SET statusProduction = 'done'
WHERE idProduction='a';
```

The system actually run the query although 0 rows were affected, but it gave me the same error message if I try this instead:

```
UPDATE tblproduction 
SET statusProduction = 'done'
WHERE idProduction='1';
```

I really don't know what is wrong, and I know it's a silly question but if anyone could help me.

Comment: can  you please provide the complete DDL for creating this table.

Comment: The error message does not fit your query, but I would check if you have an update trigger on your table, it might contain incorrect code (that will only run when your where-condition leads to an actual update, so probably not for `id='a'`).

Comment: @Used_By_Already DDL statement as down below:

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `milani`.`tblProduction` (
    `idProduction` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `dateProduction` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `statusProduction` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idProduction`))

Comment: These small comments are not the place to add code. We expect important information like that DDL to be added into the question (there is an edit link for that reason) and in the question it can be properly formatted.

Comment: @Solarflare there is a UPDATE trigger indeed, that I've dropped for testing and got the same outcome... I dropped the entire database and created it again without creating the update trigger this time and the update statement did work this time, thank you! I'm going to work on the trigger now

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for the tip, it's my first time making a question here, still getting used to the manners, I'll take more attention next time, since Solarflare suggestion solved the issue the question is solved, still I thank you for the support

Answer (score 0):

```
 please try using this method :      
 I have created a table and inserted the record like this :
                select * from tblproduction;
                +--------------+---------------------+------------------+
                | idProduction | dateProduction      | statusProduction |
                +--------------+---------------------+------------------+
                |            1 | 2018-11-19 08:22:11 | queue            |
                +--------------+---------------------+------------------+

            use update query :
            UPDATE `test`.`tblproduction` SET `statusProduction` = 'done' WHERE `tblproduction`.`idProduction` =1;

            got result :
            --------------+---------------------+------------------+
            | idProduction | dateProduction      | statusProduction |
            +--------------+---------------------+------------------+
            |            1 | 2018-11-19 08:22:11 | done             |
            +--------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem, see https://rextester.com/OQI5184

```
#MySQL 5.7.12
#'\\' is a delimiter

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblProduction;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblProduction (
    idProduction INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    , dateProduction DATETIME NOT NULL
    , statusProduction VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY (idProduction)
    ) 
;    


INSERT INTO tblProduction(dateProduction,statusProduction) VALUES ('2018-11-20','start');

SELECT * FROM tblProduction;

UPDATE tblproduction 
SET statusProduction = 'done'
WHERE idProduction=1;

SELECT * FROM tblProduction;
```

RESULTS:

```
+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
|   | idProduction |   dateProduction    | statusProduction |
+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 1 |            1 | 20.11.2018 00:00:00 | start            |
+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+

+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
|   | idProduction |   dateProduction    | statusProduction |
+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 1 |            1 | 20.11.2018 00:00:00 | done             |
+---+--------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't neither the query nor the table, there was an update trigger on this table (witch I dropped for testing and didn't work), to sum up I had to drop the database and created it all once again without creating the trigger. This time the update query worked, I'm working on the trigger now to see if I can find what's wrong